# There exists a linear map from $V_1 \otimes V_2$ to $W_1 \otimes W_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, tensor-products

I'm studying and undestanding properties about tensor product of vector spaces, so I'm here to confirm if my way to solve an exercise is correct or not.

> Let $V_1,V_2,W_1,W_2$ be vector spaces over a field $F$, and let $f_i: V_i \to W_i$ be linear maps from $V_i$ to $W_i$, for $i=1,2$.  Show that there exists a linear map from $V_1 \otimes V_2$ to $W_1 \otimes W_2$, and it is given by $g: V_1 \otimes V_2 \to W_1 \otimes W_2$ where $g(v_1 \otimes v_2) = f_1(v_1) \otimes f_2(v_2).$

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

The follow functions are bilinear:

$f = (f_1,f_2): V_1 \times V_2 \to W_1 \times W_2$ given by $f(v_1,v_2) = (f_1(v_1), f_2(v_2))$ and $\otimes_W:W_1 \times W_2 \to W_1 \otimes W_2$ given by

$\otimes_W(f_1(v_1),f_2(v_2))=f_1(v_1) \otimes f_2(v_2) $  $\hspace {1cm}$*

Futhermore $\otimes_W \circ f$ is a bilinear function from $V_1 \times V_2 \to W_1 \otimes W_2$, then by definition there exists a unique $g: V_1 \otimes V_2 \to W_1 \otimes W_2$ given by  $g(v_1 \otimes v_2)= f(v_1) \otimes f(v_2)$.

Maybe there is a mistake here, note that * makes sense if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are surjective. But if not??

Also, I know that the goal is to find a bilinear function from $V_1 \times V_2$ to $W_1 \times W_2$ using $f_1$ and $f_2$, then the result follow by definition. So can you help me?

Comment: Perhaps it is better to define $h:V_1\times V_2\to W_1\otimes W_2$ to be $h(v_1,v_2)=f_1(v_1)\otimes f_2(v_2)$ for $v_1\in V_1$ and $v_2\in V_2$.  Prove that $h$ is bilinear.  (The usual notation for the map $g$ is $f_1\otimes f_2$.)

Comment: ok, for this way I don't need $f_1$ and $f_2$ surjective?

Comment: You do not. But if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are surjective, so will be $f_1\otimes f_2$ (proof: take $t \in W_1\otimes W_2$, write that as $t = \sum_{i=1}^r w_{i,1}\otimes w_{i,2}$ with $w_{i,j} \in W_j$ for $j=1,2$; take $v_{i,j} \in V_j$ with $f_j(v_{i,j})$, so that $t = (f_1\otimes f_2)\left(\sum_{i=1}^r v_{i,1}\otimes v_{i,2}\right)$.)

Comment: (oops, I meant $f_j(v_{i,j}) = w_{i,j}$, of course)